# Qual comando SQL para mostrar o número máximo de conexões ativas ao banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, mysql

Qual comando SQL retorna o número de conexões ativas ao banco de dados?

Comment: Você escolheu outra resposta para aceitar porque ela é melhor ou está pulando de uma para outra porque não sabe que só pode aceitar uma delas e quando escolhe uma, está tirando da outra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outra opção para exibir as conexões é:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/ShowVariables.sql).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 5):

Para listar todos os status do banco, digite:

```
SHOW STATUS;
```

E para pegar eventos de execução, inclusive a própria abaixo:

```
SHOW STATUS where Variable_name='Com_show_status';
```

Para pegar somente status de conexão:

```
SHOW STATUS where Variable_name like '%connect%';
```

Answer (score 4):

Qual o comando SQL para mostrar o número **máximo** de conexões ativas(**possíveis**) no MySql?

```
select @@max_connections;
```

*@@max_connections* é uma váriável global.

Agora se quer saber quantas **conexões** estão **ativas** seria assim:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

Vou deixar um bonus na resposta, tem o comando `show processlist` que é um comando muito usado também.

Comment: Esse comando `show processlist` também é muito útil quando se deseja matar algum processo que esteja lagando o servidor, através do comando: kill [id_do_processo];